# How to get information from a twig table in js [SYMFONY]

Tags: javascript, json, symfony

Let me explain my project.

I want to create a carousel with thumbnails. So, i want to clic on thumbnails to change the main picture, classic. The pics are from the database.

My controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/team", name="team_index")
 */

public function index()
{
    $champions = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Champions::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('team/index.html.twig', [
        'champions' => $champions
    ]);
}
```

In my Twig template:

```
<script>
    var championsInfo = {{ champions|json_encode()|raw }};
</script>
```

And my JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

const championsInfo = window.championsInfo;

console.log(championsInfo);
```

});

When i do {{ dump(champions) }} , i have this:

[image]

OK!

But my console.log return me this:

[image]

I don't understand. It looks like there is nothing in my tab, while my dump shows me the opposite.

If someone has an answer for me, I'll take it!

Thank you so much and sorry for my english. (I'm french :))

Comment: Does the Champions class have a __sleep or __serialize magic method?

Comment: "I don't understand" sounds like you expect something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `Champions` object is serializable. `dump()` is NOT the same as `json_encode`. json_encode tries to look for public properties or some kind of method to serialize your object into json. For example, you could implement JsonSerializable on your object and be explicit about what you want to expose on your object, like this:

```php
class Champions implements \JsonSerializable
{
  //... your properties and methods here

  public function jsonSerialize() 
  {
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'firstname' => $this->firstname,
        'lastname' => $this->lastname,
        'image' => $this->image,
        // etc...
    ];
  }
}
```

Another option would be to use [JMS Serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) for your object serialization.